# My C Program has stopped working

Tags: c, structure

I am trying to do my homework here, which is writing a program, that shows the distances to (0,0) of a certain number of points. However for some reason(s) as soon as my program starts, windows says that it has stopped working. I tried it with two different compilers, and they don't give me any error messages.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct point getPoint();
void printPoint(struct point);
double distanceToO(struct point p);
void createArray(struct point, int);

int main() {

    int number, i;
    struct point coord[number];

    printf("Type the number of points you want to create: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    printf("\n\n");

    for(i=0;i<number;i++)
        coord[i]=getPoint();

    printf("\n\t\tPoint\tDistance to (0,0)\n");

    for(i=0;i<number;i++) {        
        printPoint(coord[i]);

        printf("\t%0.2lf", distanceToO(coord[i]));
    }

    system("pause"); 
    return 0;
}

struct point getPoint() {
    struct point p;

    printf("Type the x and the y-value for a point with a space in between: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &p.x, &p.y);

    return p;   
}

void printPoint(struct point p){
    printf("\n\t\t(%d,%d)",p.x,p.y);
}

double distanceToO(struct point p) {
    return sqrt((0-p.x)*(0-p.x)+(0-p.y)*(0-p.y));
}
```

That is what's to do in detail:

Write a Program, that first asks how many points should be created, and then asks the user for the x and y values of the points.
Then the Program should give out a table, showing the Point and the distance to (0,0).
The following functions have to be created/used:
"point getpoint()" - which asks to enter the coordinates
"void printpoint(point p)" - which prints the coordinates of the points
"double distanceToO(point p)" - returns the distance to (0,0)
Create a structure point, that has two members the x-coordinate and the y-coordinate of a point.

Can somebody give me a hint on what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: The first thing I notice is this line: `struct point coord[number];` You're trying to create an array using a number that hasn't been initialized.

Comment: You should enable warnings on your compiler, for example with gcc: -Wall -Wextra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int number, i;
struct point coord[number];
```

`number` has not been initialized, and you are using it to declare the size of the `coord` array. You will be generating an array of effectively random size on the stack, which may well cause a crash.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `number` is uninitialized when used to specify the number of elements in the array `coord`. The array is then accessed and it is not known how many elements are in they array. Read a valid value into `number` before using it and check that a valid value *has* definitely been read:

```
/* scanf() returns number of assignments made. */
if (scanf("%d", &number) == 1)
{
}
```

Always check the result of input operations to ensure subsequent code is processing variables with valid values.

Answer (score 1):

```
int number;
struct point coord[number];
```

I don't see where `number` is initialized. If you really want to use VLA, you should declare `coord` afterwards:

```
int number;

scanf("%d", &number);

struct point coord[number];
```

Otherwise, since  `number` has an automatic storage duration, its value will be undefined.

Comment: Although this requires C99+.

Comment: @Jite: Since OP already uses VLA (C99) in his original code, I guess he is aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty surprised you don't get a warning/error on this:

```
int number, i;
struct point coord[number];
```

You allocate an array of `struct point` with a size equal to an unitialized variable.

Note that if you use Visual Studio, it doesn't fully support C99 standard either so it's **not** allowed to have statements before declarations, as in:

```
int number;
number = some_number;
struct point coord; // Error, you have a statement above
```

Comment: All I know is that MS implemented some features of it but not all. Statement before declaration is something they don't support anyway, (or vice versa, declaration after statement). You might be right though, someone else would have to fill in on that part. I updated the example to not contain VLA since it wasn't needed for the example.